# Kubernetes: How do I get all pods in a namespace using the python api?

Tags: python, kubernetes, namespaces

I am using python to access my cluster. The only thing I came across, that is close is [list_namespaced_pod](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#list_namespaced_pod), which does not give me the actual names of the pods.

Comment: Did you actually check the result? It should be present under the `metadata` of an item.

Comment: you are right. Thank you very much for the reply

Answer (score 24):

As stated in the comments, you can access all information in the `metadata` of each pod in the list of pod items returned by the API call.

Here is an example:

```
def get_pods():  

    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    pod_list = v1.list_namespaced_pod("example")
    for pod in pod_list.items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (pod.metadata.name,
                              pod.status.phase,
                              pod.status.pod_ip))
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have already found the sol. for getting pod name I am posting here one more.

Below you can get pod from a namespace with particular regex (regex = if you want to search specific pod with some pattern).
Also you can check if a specific pod Exists or not with below fn.

```
from kubernetes import config , client
from kubernetes.client import Configuration
from kubernetes.client.api import core_v1_api
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from kubernetes.stream import stream
import re 

  pod_namespace = "dev_staging"
  pod_regex = "log_depl"
try:
    config.load_kube_config()
    c = Configuration().get_default_copy()
except AttributeError:
    c = Configuration()
    c.assert_hostname = False
Configuration.set_default(c)
core_v1 = core_v1_api.CoreV1Api()

    def get_pod_name(core_v1,pod_namespace,pod_regex):    
    ret = core_v1.list_namespaced_pod(pod_namespace)
    for i in ret.items:
        #print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
        pod_name=i.metadata.name
        if re.match(pod_regex, pod_name):
            return pod_name
    def check_pod_existance(api_instance,pod_namespace,pod_name):
    resp = None
    try:
        resp = api_instance.read_namespaced_pod(name=pod_name,namespace=pod_namespace)
    except ApiException as e:
        if e.status != 404:
            print("Unknown error: %s" % e)
            exit(1)
    if not resp:
        print("Pod %s does not exist. Create it..." % pod_name)
```

You can call your Functions as:

```
pod_name=get_pod_name(core_v1,pod_namespace,pod_regex)
    check_pod_existance(core_v1,pod_namespace,pod_name)
```